# Hopfield network using OCaml

Tags: function, logic, ocaml

I am currently try to build a hopfield network with Ocaml. I am having trouble making a few functions to get this all to work and don't understand how to complete them.

The first is the energy function.

Here is what I have for the function:

```
let rec energy(state, weightMatrix) =
if  weightMatrix == [] then 0.0
else
    (hd(state) *. hd(weightMatrix))/2.0 +. energy(tl(state),tl(weightMatrix));;
```

state being the state that it is in and weightMatrix being a matrix of weights. It follows the equation:

[image: Formula]

An example of this would be:

```
state =  = [1.0; -1.0; 1.0; -1.0] and 
weight = [[0.; -1.; 1.; -1.]; [-1.; 0.; -1.; 1.];[1.; -1.; 0.; -1.];[-1.; 1.; -1.; 0.]]


# energy(state,weight);;
- : float = -6.
```

When I run my function I get the following error on the last line of my function:

```
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
     int
```

EDIT: After fixing my above error I now am having trouble with this error:

```
Error: This expression has type float list list
   but an expression was expected of type float list
   Type float list is not compatible with type float
```

I think my problem can be seen in this:

```
I am getting: val energy : float list * float list -> float = <fun>
but want: val energy : float list * float list list -> float = <fun>
```

Also,

I have to create two functions that goes to the next state in the network but am having trouble thinking logically how this would be done. The outline of the function I have is:

```
let nextState(currentState, weightMatrix, alpha) =

;;
```

If anyone can clear some of this up for me that would be great!

Comment: A few things, 1) usually you don't call functions as in C. the `,` generates tuples. you can separate arguments with a space. 2) usually OCaml'ers use pattern matching instead of hd/tl directly. 3) adding type annotations can help in debugging. Use something like `(state : weightMatrix list list)` on the function arguments. You'll see that you are in fact using the weight matrix as if it were a `float list`. 4) These functions seem better suited for arrays.

Comment: @nlucaroni Thank you! Where am I calling like in C? and how would I use weightMatrix as a float list list then?

Comment: the functions `let rec energy(state, weightMatrix) = ` would be `let rec energy state weightmatrix = ` in OCaml.

Comment: @nlucaroni oh yes that makes sense! I didn't realize that. Also, Could you give me an example of how I am not making weightMatrix a float list list?

Comment: `(hd(state) *. hd(weightMatrix))`. since `hd(weightmatrix)` is a float (because you are multiplying it with `hd(state)`), and hd operates on lists, weightmatrix is inferred to be a float list.

Comment: @nlucaroni okay I think I understand what you saying. So would I not use the hd on weightMatrix or is my formula just incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The first error is caused by `/`, which is integer division. You probably want `/.`. It's very easy to forget the dots in the floating operators.

I don't understand enough about your state transition functions to give any suggestions, sorry.

Comment: @Jeffery Scofield when I enter the data in my example in I get this error back: Error: This expression has type float list list but an expression was expected of type float list Type float list is not compatible with type float. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jeffery-Scofield I edited my above question with my present problem if you could take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

My tests say:

```
# let rec energy (state, weightMatrix) =
if  weightMatrix == [] then 0.0
else
      (hd(state) *. hd(weightMatrix))/. 2.0 +. energy(tl(state),tl(weightMatrix));;
val energy : float list * float list -> float = <fun>

# let st  = [1.0; -1.0; 1.0; -1.0];;
val st : float list = [1.; -1.; 1.; -1.]

# let wg = [[0.; -1.; 1.; -1.]; [-1.; 0.; -1.; 1.];[1.; -1.; 0.; -1.];[-1.; 1.; -1.; 0.]];;
val wg : float list list =
  [[0.; -1.; 1.; -1.]; [-1.; 0.; -1.; 1.]; [1.; -1.; 0.; -1.];
   [-1.; 1.; -1.; 0.]]

# energy (st, wg);;
Error: This expression has type float list list
       but an expression was expected of type float list
       Type float list is not compatible with type float
```

Absolutely true. The head of weight is a list. You cannot divide a list by 2.0 like that.

I don't understand the formula you want to calculate, I can only say: you must decompose the list list.

Comment: Hm thats exactly what im getting. What do you mean by decompose the lsits?

Comment: Hm, have a nap first, too much staring does not help. Then compare the beginning of st with the beginning of wg. The first has one bracket, the second has two.

Comment: Decompose a list: maybe take the head of the head? But then the question is how to go one, I don't understand the formula. Make friends with List.map, List.iter, List.fold_left etc.